# Routing failure when resumn instance - BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I have created a small BizTalk application which has a single dynamic send port with the Delivery Notification == transmitted.

The send port is configured to a folder path and when the folder is not exist it suspends the orchestration. When I try to resume the orchestration after creating the folder. I'm getting two instances in the BizTalk query expression. the instance err messages are

1. Status : Suspend(Not resumable)

> Error code : 0xC0C01B4e (Routing Failure Report)
>
> Routing Failure Report for "Routing Failure Report for """

2. Status : Suspend(resumable)

> Error code : 0xc0c01b02
>
> Error Description: The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found.

NOTE:

1. I'm getting this error message only when I set the Delivery notification == transmitted
2. This works fine in some environment.

Comment: i have tested this application in several machines and it works fine in some and giving the above error in some. so i suspect that there can be some environment issues 
-Azam

Answer (score 0):

it might be because the pipeline define in the receive location was not set to be an XML pipeline. Change the pipeline and it should work.

Comment: When the messaging engine or orchestration engines publish a message to the messagebox, if no one is subscribing to that message, that is considered a routing failure.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be 2 failure instances in case of routing failure:

First is a non resumable, information only "Routing failure report".

Second is the actual message which was not routed because no subscriber found. Hence "the published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found." This is similar to **"Exception occurred when persisting state to the database."** error message we see in case of Orchestration routing failures.

Now whats is the difference:
The Suspend(resumable)instance will have the message body present, and you will be able see the contents(body) of the message. However the context properties of that message won't help you finding the reason of routing failure.

However the Suspended(Not resumable) message will have the required "Context properties" which will help you determine the reason of routing failure. That's why we see following

"This service instance exists to help debug routing failures for instance "{your message instance id}". The context of the message associated with this instance contains all the promoted properties at the time of the routing failure."